# Issue with simulating a basic crowd movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to simulate basic crowd movement and could use some help.

I have several game objects as crowds and want them to just move up or down randonmly.

I don't want to use animations as they take up too much resource with performance.
As it's a simple movement, doing the movement via code seems good in terms of performance.

I'm using the folowing code to try and replicate my movement.

```
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Jump", 0f, Random.Range(1f, 6f));
}

void Jump()
{
    transform.position += Vector3.up * 15 * Time.deltaTime;

    StartCoroutine(Gravity());
}

IEnumerator Gravity()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    transform.position -= Vector3.up * 15 * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Problem i have is that it kind of works but some objects start move higher and higher from their initial position.

I appreciate that this may not be the best way to go about it so any input would be helpful.

[Test Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l_PgEDbBXGwTcz0nTTntfjQf9PgQVHn/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why you don't wait until object "land" before next jump ? ... 1. check if object is not in jum state already  if is return 2. save position before jump ... 3. in Gravity after calculation check if results are "lower" then saved position if is set saved position 4. set not jump state

Comment: In fact it should be done completly different: in jump start you should set "up velocity" and in update you should move up based on speed and lower the speed(based on gravity) (it can be negative when object starts landing) if in update object reach starting position you set flag that object cant jump again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InvokeRepeating not using Random.Range but initially set value instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944182/invokerepeating-not-using-random-range-but-initially-set-value-instead)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/hA6KO9

Comment: @Selvin
I've tried various methods, including a similar one to what you've mentioned but no luck. The only way i've managed to get the movement to work consistantly is to apply a looping movement in Update. However, this isn't exatly what i'm looking for as i want a random delay each time the object goes up again.

Comment: @shingo I wasn't aware of this and have tried it but still get same issue.